# How do you implement ExitOnOutOfMemoryError parameter on JRockit R28?

Tags: weblogic, jvm-arguments, jrockit

My WebLogic Servers use JRockit JVM R28. We need to have the WebLogic JVMs configured to automatically shutdown/kill/exit when an OutOfMemoryError occurs.

A JRockit JVM Parameter called "ExitOnOutOfMemory" will let us accomplish this. However Oracle documentation provides incorrect and conflicting information.

1.) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionXX.html says to simply put "**-XXexitOnOutOfMemory**" into startup scripts. However, JRockit doesnt "recognize" this parameter.

2.) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionxx.htm#BABCDAIB says to put "**-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError**" into startup scripts. However JRockit does not recognize this configuration either. I believe they mistakenly copied this from Hotspot documentation.

How do i implement this parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` works as expected with JRockit R28.2.2:

```
$ jrockit-jdk1.6.0_29/bin/java -Xmx20m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError OOM
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: allocLargeObjectOrArray: [B, size 40976
    at jrockit/vm/Allocator.allocLargeObjectOrArray(JIZ)Ljava/lang/Object;(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Allocator.allocObjectOrArray(Allocator.java:349)
    at jrockit/vm/Allocator.allocArray(Allocator.java:257)
    at OOM.<init>(OOM.java:3)
    at OOM.main(OOM.java:9)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
[ERROR] Exit on OutOfMemory requested. Exiting.
JRockit aborted: Exit requested on OOM (51)
```

Which version of JRockit are you using? Did you spell the parameter correctly?

Comment: You know those moments when you feel stupid? This is one of em for me. I was testing it on a different weblogic server - i forgot this particular one was using Hotspot... It works like a charm when you deploy it on the WebLogic Server using JRockit. I would've never second guessed what i did, thanks for showing me the example!!